# Spring Boot JUnit Test Define BaseRepositoryTest for its related repository Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I have a problem about defining baserepositorytest class for annotation extending from another class.

Here is the base repository test shown below.

```
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public abstract class BaseRepositoryTests {
}
```

Here is the repository test shown below.

```
public class BookRepositoryTests extends BaseRepositoryTests {

}
```

I got this error shown below.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Plase share the complete stacktrace

Comment: @Jens I fixed the issue. I just shared with the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution shown below.

After clicking **"invalidate caches"** and restarting the **Intellij IDEA**, the issue disappeared.